# findElementRecursive not locating nested frame in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, automation, selenium

I'm using Firefox and IE8 with Selenium for automated testing of a website. The issue that I'm facing is that when I run Selenium on IE8, Selenium is not able to locate a frame nested within another.

My frame layout looks like this -

```
<frameset id="myFrameset">
    <frame name="frame1">Some Stuff</frame>  
    <frame name="frame2">  
        <frameset>  
            <frame name="nestedFrame2">Some nested Stuff</frame>  
        </frameset>  
    </frame>  
</frameset>
```

As shown above, the "nestedFrame2" is within the "frame2" frame.

I select the top-level frame initially by doing *selectFrame("relative=top")*. After this, when I try to do *selectFrame("nestedFrame2")*, Selenium reports an error stating that it could not find the frame.

Any suggestions? This works fine on Firefox. I'm using selenium-server-1.0.3.jar

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
selectFrame('frame1')
windowFocus()
selectFrame('frame2')
windowFocus()
selectFrame('nestedFrame2')
windowFocus()
```

I think, it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, our code is organised in such a way that my method accepts the name of the frame to select as an argument. I cannot reliably say when the frame is actually a nested one.

Comment: Check whether this works in IE. If it works, then you can think about changing existing code.

Comment: Figured out the reason - Starting from selenium 2, direct nested frame selection is not supported. Any nested frame selections have to be carried out by repeatedly calling WebDriver.switchTo().frame().
More information can be found at http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.selenium.devel/5553